# Django rest framework: How to reuse an app using different settings?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an application that has it's own `urls` and uses specific settings to access another api.

I would like to use this same app again within the same project, but with different urls and using a seperate endpoint.
So just setup new urls, and point to the same views from the original app but inject different settings.

For example one of my views is:

```
class SummaryVMsList(ListAPIView):
    '''
    VM Summary
    '''

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Return a list of processed vm's
        '''
        v_token = settings.VTOKEN
        base_url = settings.VURL
        v_password = settings.VPASSWORD
        v_username = settings.VUSERNAME

        session = Session()
        session.headers.update({
            'v_token': v_token
        })
        client = VClient(
            url=base_url,
            v_username=v_username,
            v_password=v_password,
            session=session
        )
        try:
            repos = client.get_summary_vms()
            return Response(data=repos, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except VError as err:
            return Response(
                data={'error': str(err)},
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
            # log the error
        finally:
            client.logout()
```

How would I be able to change the setting values: `settings.VTOKEN`, `settings.VURL`, `settings.VPASSWORD` and `settings.VUSERNAME`

Based on whick url is used:

In `urls-site1.py`

```
app_name = 'v_site1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('vm-summary', views.SummaryVMsList.as_view(), name='vms_list'),
]
```

In `urls-site2.py`:

```
app_name = 'v_site2'

urlpatterns = [
    path('vm-summary', views.SummaryVMsList.as_view(), name='vms_list'),
]
```

Comment: you could pass v_token and all other settings vars values as kwargs from urls.py

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a better idea would be to store such params in constants instead of settings. The settings in Django used for different environments, in the end, it can be hard to work with it.

Also, take note that there are two exactly the same URL `vm-summary` and it could cause a name collision.